# xPath following-sibling::nameOfTheNode does not yeld any results

Tags: xml, xpath

What is the problem with my following-sibling usage:

```
//*[@key='KEY']/following-sibling::textContent
```

If I use following xPath, everything works perfectly:

```
//*[@key='KEY']/following-sibling::*
```

I mean that this will return every sibling of the exactly correct node I was looking for.

If I replace * with a correct node name "textContent" (one of the node names the * will return), I will not get a single result.

As I'm only interested in this textContent-node, I would like to get just that one. The textContent -node is the 2nd sibling of all the siblings.

Here's the xml snippet I'm working on:

```
<text>
    <reportElement key="KEY" />
    <font isBold="true"/>
    <textContent><![CDATA[My data]]></textContent>
</text>
```

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue using the xml and query you supplied, running `Select-Xml -Path .\test.xml -XPath "//*[@key='KEY']/following-sibling::textContent"` in powershell returns the textContent node.

Comment: The XML I posted above is just a tiny fraction of the whole xml-document I've been working on. Maybe the problem is related to namespaces like Michael Kay suggested. I'm complete newbie for this so I definitely need to start thinking from scratch what is there in the namespace that could cause such problems.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out one solution all by myself, but I really doubt that this would be the optimal solution out there as this looks unnecessary complex to me:

```
//*[@key='KEY']/following-sibling::*[name() ='textContent']
```

Comment: That's not a solution, it's a workaround. It strongly suggests that you've got a namespace issue.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your XML document has a default namespace declaration `xmlns="something.com"` in the part that you haven't shown us. Namespaces make all the difference.